# Can't build after upgrading to Flutter 2.5.1

Tags: flutter

Once i upgraded to Flutter 2.5.1 my project stops build and run, giving this error:

> /Users/admin/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator_android-2.0.0/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/geolocator/location/LocationMapper.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
> if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
> ^

> symbol:   variable S
> location: class VERSION_CODES
> /Users/admin/Flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator_android-2.0.0/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/geolocator/location/LocationMapper.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
> position.put("is_mocked", location.isMock());
> ^
> symbol:   method isMock()
> location: variable location of type Location
> 2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':geolocator_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

You must have upgraded `Geolocator` to version 7.7.0, which means you will also need to update your `android/app/build.gradle` file and set the `compileSdkVersion` to 31 (it's mentioned in the [CHANGELOG](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator/changelog#770)).

If you don't want to upgrade the Android `compileSdkVersion` you should downgrade the `geolocator` to version 7.6.2 in your `pubspec.yaml`.

Comment: In fact, upgrading *compileSdkVersion* to 31 resolve the geolocator issue, but also causes another issues

Comment: What's the other issue?

Comment: If `compileSdkVersion 31` causes to to many issue , try downgrading the `geo locator` to 7.6.2 or lower . All versions above 7.6.2 requires sdk version to be 31

Answer (score 5):

The error is because the compileSdkVersion needs to be changed to 31 for Geolocator 7.7.0 and higher.

You could either do that in android/app/build.gradle file. But I wouldn't recommend it as it will cause more errors with other packages.

Instead, you could downgrade the Geolocator to 7.6.2 in the pubspec.yaml

Or use these commands to downgrade:

```
dart pub downgrade geolocator
```

Comment: still same when we change compileSdkVersion into 31. it still give an same error

Comment: Michael, have you tried downgrading the package? Also use flutter clean and pub get after making the changes

Comment: If you're making a package with CompileSdk 31, make sure the example app's compile SDK is also set to 31

Answer (score 1):

I just Upgraded my project and got this issue:

Maybe this will work for you:

**Run These commands in your terminal:**

```
dart pub downgrade geolocator_android
```

```
dart pub downgrade geolocator
```

Another way is to set Compile and Target Android version to 31.
But I will not recommend it for now coz this will lead you to many other issues.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your version is not upgraded with your packages

The following command will help you for that:

`flutter pub get`

Comment: Didn't work, even after *flutter clean*