# error: cannot find symbol if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S)

Tags: flutter

I have changed my mac and tried to run the code which was on my previous mac. I have already downloaded the same version of flutter which was On my old mac. I don't know how to resolve this error.

/Users/harisatiq/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator_android-3.0.1/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/geolocator/location/LocationMapper.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
^
symbol:   variable S
location: class VERSION_CODES

/Users/harisatiq/Documents/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/geolocator_android-3.0.1/android/src/main/java/com/baseflow/geolocator/location/LocationMapper.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
position.put("is_mocked", location.isMock());

```
                                    ^
```

symbol:   method isMock()
location: variable location of type Location
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':geolocator_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Did you try to run: flutter clean ?

Comment: yes, I already tried.

Comment: Did you check the geolocator package version? Maybe it needs an updated version of Flutter. OR, try to downgrade package's version.

Comment: You need to upgrade the compile SDK version, see this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69490468/cant-build-after-upgrading-to-flutter-2-5-1